# str.replace returns ValueError beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<body><h3>Full Results for race 376338</h3>"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"<br>"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"<br><br>"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"<br>
```

It continues like `<br> # some text <br>` for hundreds of rows.
I want to create a new line at each 
, so it is in CSV format like this:

```
<body><h3>Full Results for race 376338</h3>"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"
<br>"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"<br>
<br>"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"<br>
```

and I have this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="html.parser")

    for br in soup.find_all('br'):
        soup.replace_with("\n")
```

With this I get the error: `ValueError: Cannot replace one element with another when the element to be replaced is not part of a tree.`
What do I need to change?

Comment: What is `html_string('br')` supposed to do?  I think you meant `soup.find_all('br')` instead.

Comment: what is ```html_string```, check the type once. It might be byte string.

Comment: @JohnGordon correct I did, however that returns `ValueError: Cannot replace one element with another when the element to be replaced is not part of a tree.` whether I have `body` or `br`.

Comment: @PythonIsBae, can u post the updated code.

Comment: `want to create a new line at each` - You want to replace every `<br>` tag with the string `"\n"`?

Comment: @wwii look at the format of the second HTML in the question. I want it in that format.

Comment: @Sushanth I have updated the code in the question, and also the error

Comment: @PythonIsBae, try applying replace_with on ```br``` instead of soup.

Comment: Why do you want a newline character between each `<br><br>` pair?

Comment: @Sushanth sorry could you explain more, this isn't very clear

Comment: @wwii I am exporting this data into a CSV file, if they are not on a new line then it will only create one row in the CSV file, I want multiple rows and each row starts/ends at `<br>`

Comment: In the final result, you want the html tags to remain in the text?

Comment: @wwii no, not in the CSV, the CSV would be:
`"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"
"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the text attribute.

```
In [15]: soup.text
Out[15]: 'Full Results for race 376338"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"\n"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"\n"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"'

In [16]: soup.text.split()
Out[16]: 
['Full',
 'Results',
 'for',
 'race',
 '376338"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"',
 '"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"',
 '"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"']

In [17]: soup.text.split()[4:]
Out[17]: 
['376338"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"',
 '"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"',
 '"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"']
```

Or the `get_text` method.

```
In [24]: soup.get_text()
Out[24]: 'Full Results for race 376338"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"\n"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"\n"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"'
```

Or

```
In [25]: [text for text in soup.stripped_strings]
Out[25]: 
['Full Results for race 376338',
 '"Category","Position","Name","Time","Team"',
 '"A","1","James","20:20:00","5743"',
 '"A","2","Matt","20:15:00"']
```

Those last two are straight from the documentation.